# How to cache JSON data for offline reading in iPhone APP?

Tags: iphone, json, caching

I'm new to iPhone development and I still have some gaps that needs to be filled in the first application I'm developing. This app will consume data from a site managed by Wordpress  through the Wordpress JSON plugin, which allows to retrieve the posts in the form of a json string.

I wanted my application to store the posts in some form of caching, so that the users would only need to download the new content after the first time. Think about the Twitter App, that keeps all your previous loaded tweets and only load the new ones.

What's the best way to do that, should I save the json as a file or there are another more efficient method to keep it in cache?

Comment: did you get any solution for this? and how did you parse json in iphone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently developing an app that will deal with this kind of stuff. And I found many possible solutions.

If you still have issues with this, have a look here: http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/09/substituting-local-data-for-remote.html

If your app has to be simple, this could be perfect.

An other way could be to subclass NSURLProtocol, but I'm still investigating on this solution.